# a question regarding weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, dual-spaces

How can I prove the following statement?

Let X be a normed vector space, $x_n$ a bounded sequence in X, x $\in$ X and X* the dual space of X.

To show: $x_n$ weakly converges to $x$ as  $n\rightarrow \infty$ if and only if there exists a subset $B \subseteq X^*$ with $X^*$ is the closure of $L(B)$ (the linear hull of $B$), such that $y^*(x_n) \rightarrow y^*(x)$ for every $y^* \in B$.

(where $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$ iff for every $x^*: x^*(x_n)\rightarrow x^*(x)$).

Comment: @Michael Well, $x^*\in X^*$, and $X^*$ is the dual space of $X$. Need I say more?

Comment: @clark Then $X^*$ is one-dimensional, and hence so is $X$. A rather trivial example, no?

Comment: You cannot prove it without an additional assumption. Weakly convergent sequences are bounded.

Comment: The set $X^*$ has been defined as the closure of the linear hull of set $B$, while $B$ has been defined in terms of $X^*$, and this is circular.    There is no set $X$ defined anywhere, and the sequence $x_n$ does not have a clear relationship to anything else that has been defined. There also appear to be some undefined functions $x^*(x)$ with unclear domains. [This comment compresses my previous comments into a single one]

Comment: Thomas:  I edited your question with standard latex format. Can you clarify your question to remove the circularity and ambiguity?  (After much thought, I see that it is possible to make your question meaningful with a clear introduction of $X$ and $X^*$).  Also, can you say which aspects of the problem are difficult?  For example, this is an "if and only if" and one direction may be easy...in other words can you show your work?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. If I choose D=X*, then the first direction is trivial. But I don't know how to start with the other direction.

@Michael: Let B $\subset$ X* with X* the closure of L(B) and $x_n$ weakly converges to x in B. Then $x*(x_n) -> x*(x)  \forall x* \in B$ . The difficulty is now to show that this holds also in the closure of L(B).

Comment: For the first direction: choose B=X*, then the closure of L(B) is X*, because X* is a Banach space if the field is complete. Is this direction okay?

Comment: My edit was to change "$x^*(x_n)\to x^*(x)$ for every $x^*\in B^*$" to "$y^*(x_n)\to y^*(x)$ for every $y^*\in B^*$" for clarity only.

Comment: So if you assume there is a $B \subseteq X^*$ that satisfies $X^* = cl(L(B))$, you want to show that for all $y \in X$ we have $<x_n,y>\rightarrow<x,y>$. What if you define $f(x) = <x,y>$ and, since this is a linear function in $X^*$, there must be a function $g \in L(B)$ that is "close" to $f$, and $g$ has a specific form as a linear combination of funciotns in $B$.  I suspect that the definition of "closure" and "distance between functions" in this function space will eventually be used with bounded $\{x_n\}$ sequence (I am not sure what those exact definitions are, likely $||f||/||x||$).

Comment: If I have $B \subseteq X^*$ where $X^* = cl(L(B))$ then I thought I wanted to show that for every $y* ∈ X* : y*(x_n) -> y*(x)$. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: If $y* ∈ X*$ then there exists a functional $b* ∈ L(B) $ which is very close to $y*$ and so we get §norm(y*(x)-y*(x_n)) <= norm(y*(x)-b*(x))+norm(b*(x)-b*(x_n))+norm(b*(x_n)-y*(x_n)) -> 0. Is this correct? But where did I use that the sequence has to be bounded?

Comment: Okay, now I managed to do it and finally needed boundedness of $x_n$.
Thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: @Thomas_23 : Glad you worked it out.  I think your second-to-last comment depends on your definition of "weak convergence," whether you want to show $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$ for all linear functions $f$, or just for all inner product type functions. In the former case, to prove the $\Leftarrow$ direction you just start out fixing a particular $f \in X^*$, without defining it with the structure $f(x)=<x,y>$ as I suggested. If you want to answer your own question by posting your proof, feel free to do that (that is standard practice for stackexchange when you solve a question based on comments).

Comment: @Michael: okay, thanks. Now I understood what you ment when you said I could post my proof.. :-)
Sorry I am new here and just about finding out how everything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong. Let $X = l^2$ which is a separable Hilbert Space. Define $B:= \{e_n : n\in N\}$ and  take the sequence $\{ke_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$. Clearly for any $e_n \in B$ 
$$\left \langle e_n , k e_k \right \rangle \rightarrow  0  ,~ as ~ k \rightarrow \infty  $$
And $cl (L(B) )  = l^2 =X^*.$

But $\{ke_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is not weak convergent, since it is unbounded.

P.S.   $e_n = (0,0,0...0,1,0,...0,0,0)$ the nth coordinate is $1$.

Comment: I think this is a good example in line with the Daniel Fisher comment above.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$\Rightarrow$ : Set $B=X^*$

$\Leftarrow$ : Let $B$ be a subset of $X^*$ with the properties that $X^* = l(L(B))$ and $ \forall y^*\in B :y^*(x_n)−>y^∗(x)$

T.p.: $z^∗(x_n) \rightarrow z^∗(x) \forall z^∗\in X^∗$. Let $z^∗ \in X^∗$be arbitrarily chosen. Because $cl(L(B))=X^∗: \exists a^∗$, which is a linear combination of elements in B, i.e.: $a^∗=\sum \limits_{i=1}^m \lambda_i * a_i^* ,a_i^* \in B \forall i.\\$ Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrarily chosen.
Then, using the operator norm we get:

$\lVert z^∗(x_n)−z^∗(x) \rVert <=\lVert z^∗(x_n)−a^∗(x_n) \rVert +\lVert a^∗(x_n)−a^∗(x) \rVert+ \lVert a^∗(x)−z^∗(x) \rVert <= \\ \lVert z^∗−a^∗\rVert * \sup_n \lVert x_n \rVert +\lVert a^∗(x_n)−a^∗(x) \rVert +\lVert a^∗−z^∗\rVert ∗ \lVert x \rVert < \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} = \epsilon$.

The first and third term become arbitrarily small ($<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$) because $cl(L(B))=X^*$ and $x_n$ is bounded, the second one because it is given that holds $\forall a_i^* \in B$ and for $\epsilon > 0$ arbitrary:
 $\lVert a^∗(x_n)−a^∗(x) \rVert = \lVert a^∗(x_n - x) \rVert = \lVert \sum \limits_{i=1}^m \lambda_i * a_i^* (x_n-x) \rVert <= \sum \limits_{i=1}^m |\lambda_i| \lVert a_i^*(x_n - x) \rVert <= m*max_i|\lambda _i|*\lVert a_i^*(x_n - x) \rVert < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$, when $\lVert a_i^*(x_n - x) \rVert < \frac{\epsilon}{3*m*max_i|\lambda_i|} $.

Thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: Your proof is generally good, some stylistic and clarifying comments are: (i) In latex $\implies$, $\Leftarrow$, $\leq$, $\geq$ are [b]ack[s]lash-implies, bs-Leftarrow, bs-leq, bs-geq.  (ii) A more understandable first-sentence might be "Let $B$ be a subset of $X^*$ with the properties that...", (ii) WHen you define $a^*$ you never specify its proximity to $z^*$, (iii) As there are two things changing ($n\rightarrow\infty$ and proximity between $a^*$ and $z^*$) you might say "Let $\epsilon>0$ and let $a^*$ be a linear combination of elements of $B$ such taht $||a^*-z^*||\leq \epsilon$."

Comment: I also wonder if it can be assumed that $||x||<\infty$?

Comment: Thanks for your hints!
@Michael: How could a norm of a single point not be $< \infty$?

Comment: I guess you could have an infinite dimensional space of real-valued sequences $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and consider the norm $\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2}$.  So the sequence $(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...)$ has finite norm, but the sequence $(1,1,1,1...)$ does not.

Comment: Okay, I see. But in our lecture we defined a norm such that it is a function from a vector space to the positive real numbers. So a norm, as we defined it, can never be infinity.
Now I am really a little bit confused..

Comment: I would go to office hours and ask your professor about these issues.  He/she will be able to give you much more background, details, and context, and you will also get to know that person a little bit more. [Here is a related secret:  When grading a class, there are always students with a final weighted score that is on-or-near the threshold between two letter grades.  Teachers tend to push students above the required threshold if they have participated in class or office hours.]

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Thank you for helping me!